# Display a number of post per page in custom taxonomy page in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, taxonomy

I have the following function in my functions.php, that changes the number of posts displayed per page in the custom post type archive page. How can I also target the corresponding taxonomy page(taxonomy-case.php)? Is there something similar to "is_post_type_taxonomy"?

```
// Post number limits
function my_cptui_change_posts_per_page( $query ) {
    if ( is_admin() || ! $query->is_main_query() ) {
       return;
    }

    if ( is_post_type_archive( 'case' ) ) {
       $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 8 );
    }
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_cptui_change_posts_per_page' );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add below code inside your function and check if it's working. Don't forget to replace your category with your taxonomy name.

```
if (is_tax( 'your-category' ) ) { 
   $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 8 );
}
```

Comment: Perfect Solution...@Brijesh Dhanani

Answer (score 2):

The [is_tax()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_tax/) function should accomplish what you're looking to do.

```
// Post number limits
function my_cptui_change_posts_per_page( $query ) {
    if ( is_admin() || ! $query->is_main_query() ) {
       return;
    }

    if ( is_post_type_archive( 'case' || is_tax( 'case' ) ) ) {   // Or whatever your taxonomy name is
       $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 8 );
    }
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_cptui_change_posts_per_page' );
```

Comment: What’s the name of the taxonomy that you registered?

Comment: Did you register a custom taxonomy and apply it to your `case` post type? Or does your `case` post type just use the built in WordPress categories?